# AJAX and request-response cycle

Tags: jquery, ajax, response

I'm confused with the behavior of AJAX action. I always thought that we can request just a part of a webpage and in response, just get that especial part. But I think it isn't right (or I'm wrong!).

Say we have this page named **test.php**:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <span id="el">
            <?php echo "test"; ?>
        </span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm using a page named **ajax.php** to retrieve data from **test.php**:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>AJAX</title>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                "type": "POST",
                "url": "test.php",
                "success": function(data) {
                    $("#container").html($(data).filter("div").html());
                }
            });
    });

    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

and I know that in response **THE WHOLE test.php PAGE WOULD BE RETRIVED** and then I can filter what I want to be on my ajax.php page.

Is there a way to retrieve just a part of the page **in response** and not the whole page content?

I've used **load method** but even with load method and specifying just the element that I want to retrieve, THE WHOLE PAGE IS RETRIEVED IN RESPONSE and then filtered what I wanted:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>load</title>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#container").load("test.php #el");
    });

    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

So how can I retrieve a portion of a web page "IN RESPONSE CYCLY" AND NOT THE WHOLE PAGE?

thank you.

Comment: Please answer, I'm still waiting.

Comment: You can't. You'd need to create a new php page / function that returns only what you want.